# Is there a way to change naming settings in a .editorconfig, using JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider, editorconfig

## The Problem

I am trying to create an `.editorconfig` file using Rider. I want to be able to change all settings in the `.editorconfig` later on with Rider aswell. But it does not seem to be possible to edit the naming rules, after exporting them initially.

## What I am trying to do

Initially, I configure the coding style how I want it to be.

[image]

And then export the coding style into a new `.editorconfig` file.

[image]

Creating and exporting the `.editorconfig` works fine. The exported `.editorconfig` also contains the configured naming rules.

[image]

But when I use `Edit .editorconfig` in Rider.

[image]

There is no Naming tab anymore.

[image]

## Things I already tried

### ReSharper

I tried editing the `.editorconfig` using ReSharper, where the Naming tab is missing aswell.

[image]

### Re-exporting

I tried changing the coding style in Rider by just overwriting the `.editorconfig` that already exists, but doing so seems to be broken (or I am using something incorrectly, please tell me) as it creates "copies" of existing parts of the editorconfig. The picture shows the resulting `.editorconfig` after overwriting it. The new lines are "duplicates" of the lines above them. Overwriting multiple times creates more entries with increasing suffix numbers.

[image]

## What I am asking for

I'd love to hear someone just tell me that I am using something incorrectly and Rider actually has a feature that allows changing the Naming Style of an `.editorconfig` after creating it.
Alernatively any suggestions for a tool that can create and edit C# naming conventions conveniently in an `.editorconfig` would be great.

Comment: I'm sorry you've run into problems while using our products. I've logged them in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-484928, feel free to vote to track progress on them. We'll try to resolve them in the nearest versions. I don't know any workarounds currently, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my issue. Currently it is no big problem, as the naming is one of the things that shouldn't change in the near future for me. The last resort is always to just edit the `.editorconfig` manually, even though this is not ideal and would take more time. But nothing that would block me from using the editorconfig entirely. Great to hear that this is now something that will be included in Rider at some point.